# Exim4 Error in ACL

Tags: email, exim

I am following http://blog.edseek.com/~jasonb/articles/exim4_courier/ this guide to setup a mail server and I am getting this error when I try restart exim.

```
[....] Stopping MTA for restart:2013-07-07 07:33:17 Exim configuration error in line 440 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  error in ACL: unknown ACL condition/modifier in "warn  spam = nobody:true"
```

Comment: Which OS / Linux distribution?  Which version of Exim?  Which bit of the guide specifically since it's a large document and I don't fancy reading all of it to answer one question.  i.e. you're going to need to provide a lot more info.

Answer (score 1):

That means that you haven't configure appropriate spam handler. Until you define the spamd service like

```
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783
```

you can't use corresponding ACL condition.